# Making a CORS AJAX request without a web server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, import, local

I'm working on a website that is made on a samba share connected to a bunch of school computers. School computers being how they are, I have no access or way of setting up any webserver of any sort. I'm trying to make a header and footer for all of the HTML files on the website, but I can't include it by a standard jQuery ajax request pointing to a relative file path. Right now, the code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <html lang='en'> 

        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="javascript/libs/jquery.js"></script>

        <div id="header"></div>

        <script> 
            $.ajaxSetup({
                crossOrigin: true
            });
          $.ajax({
            url: "file://./html-templates/header.html",
            data:{"id":header},
            type: 'GET',

            success: function(){
                console.log("Added header");
            }
        });
        </script> 

    </head>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

The header file is currently only some text for testing:

```
<h2>You have successfully imported the header</h2>
```

This returns this error message from Firefox 63.0.3:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///html-templates/toolbar.html. (Reason: CORS request not HTTP).

Is there any way I could import HTML from separate files into a HTML file manually without having a web server do it for me?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For linux users, you can run this command

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/var/tmp/Chrome dev session"
```

Which will disable all the security and your will pass without any issue.

NOTE : Please do this only when testing in local systems.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has disable it for security but lucky for you Firefox can do that if you are using relative URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.get("html-templates/header.html", function (data) {
                var headerText = $(data).find('h2').text();
                $('#header').text(headerText);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the path `./` is same directory with your script you can just

```
url: "html-templates/header.html",
```